# Dependency Injection to Aspect method in Spring Boot Test (JUnit)

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

My Aspect method work when i do not use my `CronLogService` but if I Inject this I have this error:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.service.CronLogService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

**My Aspect method:**

```
@Aspect
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Slf4j
public class CronLoggerAspect {

    private final CronLogService cronLogService;
    
    @Around("@annotation(CronLogger)")
    public Object trace(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        String name = MethodSignature.class.cast(joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(CronLogger.class)
            .name();
        log.debug("start CronLogger for {}", name);
        ....
    }
}
```

**My service:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CronLogServiceImpl implements CronLogService {

    private final CronLogRepository cronLogRepository;

    @Override
    public CronLog create(CronLog cronLog) {
        return cronLogRepository.save(cronLog);
    }
    ...
}
```

I have this error only on my JUnit test (my Springboot app work!!):

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TaskService.class, CronLoggerAspect.class, CronLogService.class, CronLogRepository.class})
public class TaskTest {

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;
    
    @Test
    void testCronLoggerSuccess() throws CronException {
        taskService.testCronLogger("test Success");
    }
}
```

My test service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class TaskService {

    @CronLogger(name = "unit test")
    public void testCronLogger(String param) throws CronException {
        log.info("testCronLogger for {}", param);
        ...
    }

}
```

My `CronLogRepository`

```
public interface CronLogRepository extends JpaRepository<CronLog, String> {

}
```

**EDIT:**

```
//@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CronLogServiceImpl implements CronLogService {

    @Autowired
    private CronLogRepository cronLogRepository;
```

**test:** No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.repository.CronLogRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

**springboot:** OK

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CronLogServiceImpl implements CronLogService {

    private CronLogRepository cronLogRepository;
```

**test:** no spring error but `cronLogRepository` is null. so `cronLogRepository.save` return a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

**springboot:** java.lang.NullPointerException: null on `CronLogServiceImpl.create`

Comment: CronLogServiceImpl is not in the list of classes in @SpringBootTest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @SpringBootTest(classes = {TaskService.class, CronLoggerAspect.class, CronLogService.class, CronLogRepository.class})

Probably the error is in this line, try replacing it with just `@SpringBootTest` and if it works, then the error is in context configuration.
You need to add, I think, `CronLogServiceImpl` to the list of classes to add to context.

Does this solve your problem ? Let me know in the comments.

Comment: private final CronLogRepository cronLogRepository; --> remove final from here ...

Comment: It has to do with injecting the repository. You can try removing final putting @Autowired directly on the field

Comment: thanks, your solution must not be far from working, there is just one more problem left. Error: `No qualifying bean of type 'com.orange.planning.modules.admin.repository.CronLogRepository'`

Comment: Show me the code for CronLogRepository. Add it to the question ! :3 :D

Comment: I change `CronLogService` by `CronLogServiceImpl` in `@SpringBootTest`. I remove `final` in `CronLogServiceImpl`. So now, no spring error but `cronLogRepository` is null.  so `cronLogRepository.save` return a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Try using just @SpringBootTest ... if this works, its fine, you can leave it like this

Comment: YES, `@SpringBootTest` solve my problem. I can re add `final` and use Lombok :)